# programmatically close win8 app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I've begun tinkering with making windows 8 apps And I want to make an exit button.

The problem is that `Environment.Exit()` and `this.Close()` that I'd use in winforms isn't in scope here.

anyone know how to close the app Programmatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Application.Current.Exit();
```

But closing a Metro app is not recommended. It is usually suspended.

Comment: This just minimizes the app.

Comment: Yay, any update on this? Is there a suspend counter part for this?

Answer (score 5):

```
Application.Exit
```

But be careful. You can fail certification by having code which forcefully closes the App. Make sure to read up on [Certification Guidance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx) if you plan to release to the store:

> Your app must neither programmatically close nor offer UI affordances to close it. Windows 8 Process Lifetime Management closes Windows Store apps automatically.

Comment: Microsoft has relaxed their guidance on this a bit on req 3.6 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx#acr_changelog

Answer (score 2):

```
Application.Current.Exit();
```

This **was** not allowed, but requirement 3.6, which used to not allow this, seems to be removed :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh694083.aspx#acr_changelog